# How can I find numbers which assert 0.01x * y = 0.01y * x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

Yesterday, somebody told me that `45% of 37 = 37% of 45`. I did the math and that's actually true.

So from that, we know that:

$${45\over 100}\times 37 = {37\over 100}\times 45$$

I want to find more numbers which fulfill this property, with something like this:

$${x\over 100}\times y = {y\over 100}\times x$$

Without fractions:

$$0.01x\times y = 0.01y\times x$$

However, I have two unknown variables and only one equation, and I'd need two to be able to find solutions.

**How can I solve this equation?** I'd be able to solve it if I had a system of linear equations, but I have only one...

**EDIT**: I've just realized... every combination of `x` and `y` will work with this. Sorry, I didn't realize it before. I (stupidly) thought it wouldn't.

Comment: Consider adding a tag for a broader subject area to which the question belongs. This will improve the visibility of your question.

Comment: @MiceElf which tag should I add? I couldn't think of anything descriptive about this question...

Comment: Multiplication is commutative.

Answer (score 1):

This is always true.

$.01x*y=(.01x)y=.01(xy)=.01(yx)=(.01y)x=.01y*x$

Comment: Every x and y will fulfill this. All I used is commutativity and associativity of multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote this statement $$ {x\over 100}\times y = {y\over 100}\times x $$

You can write this as $$ \frac{xy}{100} = \frac{xy}{100} $$ which is true for all $x$ and $y$